# Client - Server database programming after learning core Java

Tags: java, sql, sockets, network-programming

I believe I have learned all the core Java parts about how to make a program on a single computer, but now I want to create a client/server program where the client accesses a database on a server.  My original thought was that I had to begin learning MySQL, but it now seems that this is two steps beyond what I know and that there must be a step missing between what I know of Java and what can be done with SQL.  I believe I need to know how to actually allow two computers to exchange code with each other.  More recently I thought the answer was in an area called Network Programming or Socket Programming, but just now I read the first sentence on [this webpage](http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/) which suggests that Socket Programming is not the most direct route to obtaining this knowledge.

> Although most programmers probably do network programming using a nice
>   library with high-level application protocol (such as HTTP) support
>   built-in, it's still useful to have an understanding of how to code at
>   the socket level.

So, I need to be set straight.  Yesterday I bought these four books:

- [TCP/IP Sockets in Java: Practical Guide for Programmers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123742552)
- [A Tutorial on Java Socket Programming and Source Code Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3659314455)
- [Java Network Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449357679)
- [Learning Network Programming with Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1785885472)

Am I on the right track or is there some library that I need to focus on?  Mainly, what is the next step after learning core Java to be able to develop the kind of program I desire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are trying to do some basic web application where using a browser you need to view data stored in your database.

If this is the case, I suggest you to try installing/learning below
1) Tomcat (for running server)
2) Java (you know this already)
3) JDBC library (For connecting java with MySQL)
4) MySQL

Once you can make a sample web application running using above 4 things, you will get a small overview of what is happening. After that you can go deep by exploring how each part is communicating with each other and in that journey you can use your newly purchased books.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what about a local connection between two of my computers at home?

Comment: First try everything on a single computer. Later install MySQL on another computer and in MySQL change settings to allow connection within the LAN. Now try connecting to MySQL from the other PC through LAN using IP address. If you can connect, do the same in JDBC.